# Timestamp doesn't convert from string into float

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, type-conversion

```
for post in posts:       
        float(post[2])     # convert to float
print(type(posts[0][2]))   # print the type 1st row of the 2nd column
print(posts[0][2])
```

The output is:

```
<class 'str'>
1433213314.0
```

Why it hasn't converted into float?..

Comment: Could you please share an example of posts. So that it would be good to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float` doesn't convert the argument in-place. It returns the result of the conversion. So you have to put it somewhere. In your case, you can just do `post[2] = float(post[2])`